# Prove that all entries of the nth row of Pascal's Triangle are odd given that $n=2^k-1$

Tags: combinatorics

Like the title says, I'm to prove that if $n=2^k-1$ then all entries of the nth row of Pascal's Triangle are odd. I know a couple of things that I can use for this, for one I know that I can describe the $j$th entry as $\binom{n}{j}$, and I know that $\binom{n+1}{j} = \binom{n}{j-1} + \binom{n}{j}$. I think the way to go is to show that $\binom{n}{j-1}$ and $\binom{n}{j}$ have opposite parities, thereby showing that their sum must be odd. The clincher is that I'm only allowed to use direct or contrapositive proof, i.e. no induction allowed.

Comment: "No induction allowed" ought to be banned from classrooms. It's an elegant form of proof, and if we get into the nitty gritty details, just the fact that we are using the natural numbers means that we are automatically using induction, at least somewhere deep down.

Comment: Can you prove that $\binom{2^k}j$ is even for $0<j<2^k$? It then follows that $\binom n{j-1}$ and $\binom nj$ have the same parity for all $j$ (since they add up to an even number). But $\binom n0$ is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it this way: the explicit formula for an entry is

$$\binom nj  = \dfrac{n!}{j!(n-j)!} = \dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-(j-1))}{j!} = \dfrac{(2^k-1)(2^k-2)\cdots(2^k-j)}{1\cdot 2\cdots j}$$

$2$ divides $2^k-i$ the same number of times it divides $i$ for $1 \leq i \leq j$, so all factors of $2$ on the top and bottom will cancel.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit in the last line of that?

Comment: @Peatherfed If we split each $2^k-i$ into prime factors,  and each $i$ into prime factors, all the factors of $2$ will cancel.  This leaves only odd factors in the numerator, so the number must be odd.  Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: OK, I see it now, it was especially helpful for me two split up that final fraction in the form (2^k-i)/i for 1<i<j. Is there a "rigorous" way to put this, or is what you wrote in your answer acceptable?

Comment: @Peatherfed "Acceptable" to whom?

Comment: In the sense that the answer is rigorous I guess?

Comment: @Peatherfed Well, rigor is somewhat relative... it certainly wouldn't impress a computerized proof-checker, but I wasn't going for that level of rigor. If you want to make it a bit more rigorous, you first prove (based on uniqueness of prime factorization, and $2$ being the only even prime) that each positive integer $i$ has a unique factorization $i=2^mx$ where $x$ is odd. Then you can show that if $i = 2^mx < 2^k$, and $2^k - i = 2^py$, where $x,y$ are odd, then $m=p$. (You'd do this by noting that $i+(2^k-i) = (2^mx+2^py) = 2^k$, so $2^m,2^p|(2^mx+2^py)$, so $2^m|2^p$ and $2^p|2^m$.)

Comment: @Peatherfed Then making the substitutions $i = 2^{m_i}x_i$ and $2^k - i = 2^{m_i}y_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq j$ in the fraction in my answer, you end up with $\frac{\prod_i 2^{m_i}x_i}{\prod_i 2^{m_i}y_i} = \frac{\prod_i x_i}{\prod_i y_i}$. The numerator and denominator are each products of odd integers, so they are each odd integers. The quotient of an odd integer, if it is an integer, must be odd (this follows again from the fact that the product of odd integers is odd), so the final answer is odd.